# How convert world clock format with dropdown menu or button (12/24hour)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to change the time format of the script results below with the drop down menu? Thanks.

```js
function show()
{
    var time=new Date()
 document.write("London " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/London", hour: "2-digit", minute:"2-digit" })+ "<br>");
 document.write("Paris " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/Paris", hour: "2-digit", minute:"2-digit" })+ "<br>");
    document.write("Tokyo " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo", hour: "2-digit", minute:"2-digit" }));
}

show();
//Output
// London : time
// Paris : time
// Tokyo : time
```

```html
<p>Format : 
  <select name="select" id="select">
    <option value="12">AM/PM</option>
    <option value="24">24 Hours</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: You need to put each city's time into an element you can get a handle on, for example `<span id="london-time">09:30</span>` and then have an event listener on the select box being changed to go through each of those span time elements and update their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `hour12: false,` to your existing code when `24 Hours` option is selected. Sample below, check for `else` condition for the change.

```js
function show(format) {
    var time = new Date();
    var str = "";

    if (format === "12") {
        str += "London " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/London", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" }) + "<br>";
        str += "Paris " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/Paris", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" }) + "<br>";
        str += "Tokyo " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" });
    }
    else {
        str += "London " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/London", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" }) + "<br>";
        str += "Paris " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Europe/Paris", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" }) + "<br>";
        str += "Tokyo " + time.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" });
    }

    document.getElementById("displayTime").innerHTML = str;
}

window.onload = function() { show("12") };
```

```html
<p>Format :
    <select name="select" id="select" onchange="show(this.value)">
        <option value="12">AM/PM</option>
        <option value="24">24 Hours</option>
    </select>
</p>

<div id="displayTime"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved my life.I hope can learn more, thank you very much